# How to get UiBinder Styles to Act The Same as From a .css File?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I apologize for the vague title, but I can't think of a better way to ask it. I'll try to be very specific:

So lets say I make a new GWT/AppEngine application and have the default sample application. I see the buttons, and decide they are nice and I'd like to use them. In the css file the styles given to the buttons are:

```
button.send {
   margin-top: 10px;
   float: right;
   padding: 10px 14px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5D9AFE),
       to(#4785E8) );
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5D9AFE, #4785E8);
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: none;
}

button.send:active {
   margin-top: 10px;
   float: right;
   padding: 10px 14px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4785E8),
       to(#5D9AFE) );
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4785E8, #5D9AFE);
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: none;
}

button.centerbtn {
   float: none;
   display: inline;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

button.centerbtn:active {
   float: none;
   display: inline;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But if I were to try and use these inside of UiBinder they won't be applied to the button automatically. Even if I manually apply it to the button by setting it's style, it then won't change visual (as in pop up and down) when I click on it.

I'm having the desire to be able to do this enough that I thought I'd ask, as I'm trying to do similar things with popups, dialog boxes, etc.

Comment: How do you set the button's style? It _should_ work (note that you'd have to use `literal()` around your gradients, as CssResource –used by UiBinder's ui:style– uses a CSS2 parser, that doesn't support most of CSS3 syntax)

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you can have conditional CSS in your UiBinder files as if they were a CSS resource. (You'll send a little less to each browser, but the right parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the literal() in as per the person's comment above fixed it, as did programatically changing the class name.

Comment: Also, if you use the conditional markup in CSS, make sure it comes before any CSS statements by putting it at the top of the file, or the GWT parser will fail. That isn't in the docs.